# What does "But there I go, adopting" imply?

Tags: grammar

[Source](http://www.berfrois.com/2013/11/ron-rosenbaum-on-auden-larkin-and-love/)

I thought that it meant "OK, I will accept this self loathing of the line but hey, the line is not bad, why bother?"

Am I right? If I am right, I thought "and" should be "but"

**But there I go, adopting Auden’s retroactive self-loathing of the line, and I’m not sure it was such a crime against poetry.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author employs *and* to call attention to the fact that he has allowed himself to be seduced by his "self-consciously highbrow culture" into adopting Auden's attitude to the line **despite** the fact that he doesn't think that attitude is justified.

This is a common way of expressing the notion that one the more culpable for acting against one's true belief or interest:

> Dave congratulated him, too, **and** Dave voted for the other guy.
>   She's a hell of a salesman. I bought twelve boxes, **and** I don't even like Girl Scout cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the original, but the question to my mind is whether "it" here refers to "the line" or the "retroactive self-loathing". If "it" refers to the self-loathing, then the "and" makes sense: I adopt it, AND it is not a crime. If "it" refers to the line, then it would seem that "but" would be more appropriate.